# VB.net Updating a List variable inside of a For Each Loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, each

```
Dim aProductos As List(Of Producto)
Dim aRegistros As New List(Of Registro)
Dim selectedProd As New Producto

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Add to cart
    Dim insert As Boolean = True
```

PROBLEM STARTS HERE vvv

```
    For Each reg In aRegistros
        If (reg.id_prod = Integer.Parse(lbCodigo.Text)) Then

            Dim r As New Registro
            r.id_prod = reg.id_prod
            r.cantidad = reg.cantidad + Integer.Parse(nudUni.Value.ToString)
            reg = r
            insert = False
        End If
    Next
```

PROBLEM FINISHES HERE ^^^

```
    If insert Then
        Try
            Dim r As New Registro
            r.id_prod = selectedProd.cod
            r.cantidad = Integer.Parse(nudUni.Value.ToString)
            aRegistros.Add(r)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Create and insert register: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
    MostrarFactura()
End Sub

Private Sub MostrarFactura() << Updates a listview to see the products you got
    listaProd.Items.Clear()
    For Each registro In aRegistros
        For Each producto In aProductos
            If registro.id_prod = producto.cod Then
                MsgBox(registro.cantidad)
                listaProd.Items.Add(producto.nombre + " --- " + registro.cantidad.ToString + " -> " + (producto.precio * registro.cantidad).ToString + "€")
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that i update "reg" but when loop finishes reg is not updating the value inside of the list

Thanks in advance :S

Comment: You can't add/remove from the list on which you have started an enumeration with foreach.

Comment: So what can i use instead? Maybe just with a while loop?

Comment: You can change the property of the current reg variable. _reg.cantidad = reg.cantidad + Integer.Parse(nudUni.Value.ToString);_

Comment: Just switched from creating the object and inserting it to just change the variable, it changes it, and i can print it when im inside of the loop, but not when im outside of it, just in the line before MostrarFactura()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `For Each`, you can use an integer to specify the position in the list.

```
For x = 0 to aRegistros.Count -1
  Dim reg = aRegistros(x)
  Dim r As New Registro
  r.id_prod = reg.id_prod
  r.cantidad = reg.cantidad + Integer.Parse(nudUni.Value.ToString)
  aRegistros(x) = r
  insert = False
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much dave, i didn't realize about that since i did not remember there was a simple indexed for loop!!

Comment: Just to say, the problem appears to be that i was using structures, and i guess they cannot be changed when inside of a list or something like that. The fact is that i changed them for real classes and it works well!!